# with precss, the content of :root {} in my CSS is being lost

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, webpack

I have noticed that after processing with precss, the content of :root {} in my CSS is being lost. I would appreciate any help from the community to resolve this issue.

here is my webpack config

```
{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: true,
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: () => [
                            postcssImport(),
                            precss,
                            cssnano({
                                autoprefixer: {
                                    add: true,
                                    remove: true,
                                    browsers: ['last 2 Chrome versions'],
                                },
                                discardUnused: false,
                                mergeIdents: false,
                                reduceIdents: false,
                                safe: true,
                            }),
                        ],
                    },
                },
            ],
        }
```

when i remove the precss, and recompile the code , i saw the :root{} come out

and i find this :

```
WARNING in ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":true}!./~/postcss-loader?{}!./static/css/app.css
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-custom-properties: heme.css:10:3: Custom property ignored: not scoped to the top-level :root element ([data-theme="dark"] { ... --primary: ... })
```

Comment: where is the :root stylerule written. is it nested within some other parent element?